# string = "Brand new bicycle\r\n" Как удалить \?

Tags: ruby

```
string.gsub(/\/, "")
```

не работает. "\" не отобразился и тут между //

Comment: А какую проблему решаете?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Нельзя удалить то, чего и так нет. В приведенной строке нет символа "\". `\r` и `\n` это два служебных символа - возврат каретки и новая строка. Это все равно, что удалять символ "ь" из "весы".